# I push a local branch to remote, and the resulting name is "master" while it should be v1

Tags: git, github, branch, github-for-windows

It's as simple as I'm trying to push to remote a branch called `v1` but when I run the command `git push origin v1`, GIT client says:

> [new-branch] v1 -> master

...and it should be `v1 -> v1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Run `git config -l` to see if there is `push.default=upstream`. If there is, and if `v1`'s upstream is `remotes/origin/master`, `origin/master` or `master`, `git push origin v1` will be equivalent to `git push origin v1:master`, which updates the `master` branch in the remote repo.

Comment: @ElpieKay Your comment has driven me to the solution: `git push origin v1:v1`

Comment: @ElpieKay Can you post an answer explaining everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git push origin v1:refs/heads/v1` will create the remote branch for you. The left side of the colon is the local branch, the right side is the remote branch. If the right side doesn't exist, it will be created. After that, you may want to use `git branch -u` as suggested by Tim to set the upstream tracking info correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are telling us the whole story (i.e., what lead up to the problem)?

```
$ git branch xyzzy
$ git push origin xyzzy
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To xxx@yyy:/zzz
 * [new branch]      xyzzy -> xyzzy
```

The simple `git push origin xyz` should indeed create a new branch on the remote without any need for `:`or whatever.

Can you post your `.git/config` file?

Comment: Now I could solve it. My first attemp was doing like you and this the reason that made me came here to ask the question :/

Comment: Well actually I was renaming a branch from "master" to "v1".